# Set ImageSource in UserControl doesnt work

Tags: wpf, image, binding, user-controls

I had a large controle (bunch of labels etc.) that I used that often I wanted to extract that as an UserControl.

**Working Code Before:**

```
       <Image Source="/Images/MainWindow/Label.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

**Code Now:**

New User Control xaml:

```
         <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

UserControl Property:

```
        public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
```

Call of UC:

```
        <uc:TitleUC x:Name="TitleBar" ImageSource="/Images/MainWindow/Label.png" />
```

Sadly the image doesn't show and I can't find any information why not or how to debug it.

Comment: Is PropertyChanged raised in the property `public ImageSource ImageSource`? 
And how do you set the DataContext in your UserControl?

Comment: A control should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Bindings to the control's own properties should be done by RelativeSource or ElementName Bindings. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a control is pointless at best. The property should be a dependency property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding in the UserControl's XAML should use the UserControl instance as source object, not the current DataContext:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" .../>
```

---

You should also declare the `ItemsSource` property as dependency property, in order to make it bindable and to be able to set it by a Setter in a Style or a Trigger.